# Getting more volts out of 3.7v battery

Tags: batteries

I have a 3.7v 12A rechargable battery I'm using in my electric cigarette. I noticed that the cigarette can go up to 75W. I want to turn 3.7 into 9v to give more voltage to my motor, what component can I use to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What motor are you talking about?

Comment: what does a motor have to do with an e-cig?  What is the motor DCR after boost impedance conversion equivalent on source? (3.7/9)^2 or about 6x surge current of motor which is 8x avg or 48x motor rated current now on battery.  doh

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 both use battery, doh. I'm a beginner, I clearly asked 'what component' you think if I knew what 'boost impedance conversion' is, I would ask this question?

Comment: @0x29a the impedance of the voltage source compared to the motor  must be low for an efficient power source.  We measure this by voltage changes over current changes or R=ΔV/ΔI for a battery we desire to be low compared to DC resistance of motor coil.. THe motor impedance rises when speeding up for different reasons (back EMF) compared to tungsten heaters which rise due to heat.  So in a way you are ok to compare heater coils or lamps to motors except the duration of the surge current or time to reach full temp or speed. Surge currents can be 8x more or less

Comment: In short you may need to match the battery voltage and capacity to the motor voltage to avoid power losses.

Comment: Buy a battery capable of delivering more amps (e.g. LG HG20) and change your coil(s) so the resistance is lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single component, but a boost converter is what you're after.

Comment: This will be impractical at the power levels and size concerned.  Those who are extremely absurd about what they inhale without thought to health issues  usually use lower resistance heaters, iirc called sub-ohming or something like that.

Comment: Single component: brain.  [Sorry, I couldn't resist.]